# Prepare SQL Server for re-installing windows 10 using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working with big SQL database which is located in hard drive(D:) and uses almost 80% of the space, so there is no space for backup files. I use SSMS v17.3 to manage SQL Server. I have windows 10 on SSD (C:), I wan't to reinstall it.

How to make sure that I will be able to connect to the database after refreshing windows?

Comment: [Database Detach and Attach (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-detach-and-attach-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Are you asking if your databases, located on a separate partition to your OS, will be ok if you reinstall windows? Also, not backing up is rarely a good idea. Have you considered backing up to a network or external device?

Comment: Have you considered backup compression? Depending on how much empty space is in your database, it might actually work.

Comment: @RogerWolf, I don't have enough space for backup